# Retrieve a regular file using PHP Curl when the Content-Length isn't set or is zero

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to retrieve a file from a url I have not control over. The url doesn't set the content length header for the size of the file (i.e. it's always set to zero(0)).

Despite this the file gets downloaded properly using a browser.

However, I'm trying to replicate the same action using curl, but curl always returns empty data. I'm guessing this is because of the "Content-Length: 0" set by the server.

How can I bypass this and fetch the file anyway just as a browser does it?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$response = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

All I get using this is a bunch of headers:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Date: Wed, 05 Mar 2014 04:48:23 GMT
> Server: Apache/2.2
> Content-disposition: attachment; filename="file.txt"
> Content-Length: 0
> Vary: User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
> Content-Type: text/plain
> ```

However, the file is downloaded fine when I use a browser.

**NB**: I also noticed the same behaviour with curl in the command line!

Answer (score 0):

After considerable research, which included monitoring the browser request (i.e. headers) logs and trolling the curl forums, I realized that the browser was sending the 'Accept-Encoding' request header which provides support for compressing the response data.

I was able to mimic this with the command line option ***--compressed***

In php you have to modify the request thus:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$response = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```